# Pulling all GPOs with orphaned SIDs in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, gpo

I am working on a script for decommissioning servers. The script deletes the VM, removes the A.D. object, any DNS records, and ultimately removes the object from any GPOs. Everything is working but the last part. I have begun with doing something like this:

```
$aServers = Import-Csv -Path 
$domain = "myCompany.com"
$GPOs = Get-GPO -Domain $domain -All | Select DisplayName

$aReport = @()
    foreach ($server in $aServers) {
        foreach($gpo in $GPOs) {
            $myObject = New-Object PSObject
            try {
                If (!((Get-GPPermissions -DomainName $domain -Name $gpo.DisplayName -TargetName $server.ComputerName -TargetType Computer -ErrorAction Stop) -eq "")) {                   
                    $myObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Server" -Value $($server.ComputerName)
                    $myObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "GPO" -Value $($gpo.DisplayName)
                }
                $aReport += $myObject
            } catch {
                Write-Host "$($server.ComputerName) not found in $($gpo.DisplayName)"
            }
        }
```

...which works but is ugly and slow. I thought there was a way to do this more simply, along the lines of this:

```
Get-GPO -All | 
   foreach{
      Get-GPPermissions -Guid $_.Id -All | 
         Where-Object {$_.Trustee -like "S-1-5-*"}
   }
```

...but I cannot seem to get the syntax correct. I am sure I am missing something stupid simple, but any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I think I am getting closer. This seems to work:

```
    $aReport = @()
    $domain = "mycompany.com"
    $aGPOs = Get-GPO -Domain $domain -All | Select DisplayName, Id

    foreach ($gpo in $aGPOs) {
        $myObj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
        if ($perms = Get-GPPermissions -DomainName $domain -Guid $gpo.Id -All | 
            Where-Object {$_.Trustee.Name -like ""}) {
                $myObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "GPO" -Value $gpo.DisplayName
                $myObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Member Name" -Value $perms.Trustee.Name
                $myObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Member SID" -Value $perms.Trustee.Sid

                $aReport += $myObj
        }
    }
```

Although it is slow. It also does a single pass, lumping all orphaned SIDs for a particular GPO into a single line. As the eventual goal is to be able to cycle through and delete these orphans, I am either going to have to massage the data at another stage or add another for loop to get each SID per line, something like this:

```
    $aReport = @()
    $domain = "mycompany.com"
    $aGPOs = Get-GPO -Domain $domain -All | Select DisplayName, Id

    foreach ($gpo in $aGPOs) {
        if ($perms = Get-GPPermissions -DomainName $domain -Guid $gpo.Id -All | 
            Where-Object {$_.Trustee.Name -like ""}) {
                foreach ($perm in $perms) {
                    $myObj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
                    $myObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "GPO" -Value $gpo.DisplayName
                    $myObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Member Name" -Value $perm.Trustee.Name
                    $myObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Member SID" -Value $perm.Trustee.Sid
                    $aReport += $myObj
                }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the suggestions thus far; still open to any ways to make it better.

Edit2:

I finally cobbled this together after some shameless borrowing from another post. Seems to work well; clears all orphaned SIDs from 100+ test policies in less than a minute:

```
Function Remove-GPOUnknownSIDs {
   param ([parameter(mandatory = $true)][Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Gpo]$GPO)
   $name = $GPO.DisplayName
   $gpoSecurity = $GPO.GetSecurityInfo()
   $UnknownSIDs = $gpoSecurity.Trustee | Where SidType -Like "Unknown"
      foreach($UnknownSID in $UnknownSIDs) {
         $SIDToRemove = $UnknownSID.Sid.Value
         $gpoSecurity.RemoveTrustee($SIDToRemove)
         $GPO.SetSecurityInfo($gpoSecurity)
      }
}

$domain = "mycompany.com"
$aGPOs = Get-GPO -Domain $domain -All
   foreach($GPO in $aGPOs) {
      Remove-GPOUnknownSIDs $GPO
   }
```

Comment: you need to use `Foreach-Object` instead of `foreach` to actually get an object through the pipeline ($_)

Comment: @Theo The `foreach` used in the second code block is an alias that calls the ForEach-Object command. In other words, it should (and does) work.

Comment: I would not use the `Add-Member` cmdlet but create the `PSObject` in once: `$myObj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{"GPO" = $gpo.DisplayName; "Member Name" = $perm.Trustee.Name; "Member SID" = $perm.Trustee.Sid}`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I can see the benefit of putting it in a single line, but functionally it appears to be the same: runs no faster that the way I have it written.

Comment: There is no functional difference. It is really just a matter of style. Personally I do both. I add the properties when I create the object but I put each object on its own line.